# vba If Combo box selection equals "Location" then write "Loc"

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I need to assign a code to the combo box selection. So my combo box has Locations list. If United States is selected, US is then written in the database, If United Kingdom, then UK, if Philippines, then PH. I don't know how to put this into a vba code since i have to combine this with another combo box value like a string.

```
 .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = cmbLoc.Value & "_" & cmbProg.Value
```

Wherein cmbLoc is the combo box i need help with.

Comment: You need a lookup table either in a hidden sheet or perhaps building a dictionary in the code itself where match `country code` to `country name`. Then you can pass `cmbLoc.Value` into the lookup and return the code in a variable. Then pass that variable in place of `cmbLoc.Value` when setting the cell value.

Comment: Hi Scott! So i created a table in my Info worksheet where Column A has the Location and Column B has the Loc Code. Sorry but i think i got lost here > Then you can pass cmbLoc.Value into the lookup and return the code in a variable. Then pass that variable in place of cmbLoc.Value when setting the cell value. –

Comment: See my answer Cielo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table is in `Info` worksheet where Country is column A and Code in column B, update your code to this:

```
 Dim sCode as String
 sCode = Worksheets("Info").Columns(1).Find(cmbLoc.Value,lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(,1)

 .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = sCode & "_" & cmbProg.Value
```

bear in mind that I did not do any error checking, so I assume country will always bear there. Also, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I was actually in the process of using the Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup now but have not tested it yet. i will also give your answer a test and get back to you.